# upload user details with pdf file to server

Tags: android, sql-server, pdf, android-volley

I am trying to implement user complaint application, this application containing user data and a pdf file is sending to the server but I am failed any please help me.

- 4 edit text
- one browse button
- one submit button

**Browse button code**

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("application/pdf");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Pdf"), PICK_PDF_REQUEST);
```

**Submit code**

```
String name = fil_name.getText().toString().trim();
//getting the actual path of the image
String path = FilePath.getPath(this, filePath);
```

how can get the file name ?

broswed pdf is stored in any temporary location ?

how can i send brwosed pdf via volley?

please help me

Answer (score 0):

you can use [VolleyPlus](https://github.com/DWorkS/VolleyPlus)

```
    SimpleMultiPartRequest smr = new SimpleMultiPartRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL,
        new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d("Response", response);               
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.alert_comment_sukses, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();              
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
smr.addStringParam("param string", " data text");
smr.addFile("param file", imagePath);
RequestQueue mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
mRequestQueue.add(smr);
```

Comment: if don't min can your sample whole code, am new in android, can you??

Comment: first step add VolleyPlus sdk to your project
implementation 'dev.dworks.libs:volleyplus:+'
then on submit button click body add above code.
for each string data add one string parm:
smr.addStringParam("name", "value");
and in addFile name of your file and string path